# Set text retreived by location manager inside sharingIntent Extra

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, share, locationmanager

i'd like to ask how to set text inside `TEXT_HERE`

> sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TEXT_HERE);

---

I have retrieved the current longitude and latitude by gps using location manager. Then i made these two values to be set in `longitude_placeholder` and `latitude_placeholder` to show the users their current position.
Like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_placeholder);
    TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_placeholder);

    longitude.setText("Longitude :" + location.getLongitude());
    latitude.setText("Latitude : " + location.getLatitude());
}
```

Then i made a button `btn_share` and made the `onClick` method to make the sharingIntent function.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, LONGITUDE_HERE); 
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, LATITUDE_HERE); 
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

Now the question. how can i set the `LONGITUDE_HERE` and `LATITUDE_HERE` with the values retrieved with the `onLocationChanged` method to share the longitude and latitude values by a button click?

---

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare 2 Strings as Global

String LONGITUDE_HERE="";

String LATITUDE_HERE="";

```
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
  {
  TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_placeholder);
  TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_placeholder);

longitude.setText("Longitude :" + location.getLongitude());
latitude.setText("Latitude : " + location.getLatitude());

 LONGITUDE_HERE=""+location.getLongitude();
 LATITUDE_HERE=""+location.getLatitude();

  }
```

And in onClick

```
  public void onClick(View v)
   {
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    if(LONGITUDE_HERE!=null&&LATITUDE_HERE!=null)
     {
   sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT1, LONGITUDE_HERE); 
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT2, LATITUDE_HERE); 

}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

Comment: I am actually a bit confused by the question.But I thought this is what you require. Do not down vote me too..:)

Comment: Also use a Global flag to make sure the location is changed and check that flags value in onClick to proceed, Revert to the default flag value before startActivity().

Comment: just checked out with your code and it works fine but when using `String LONGITUDE_HERE="";` , you should use `LONGITUDE_HERE= String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());` because of some java.lang.String invalid argument.

Comment: may i ask what is `LONGITUDE_HERE!=null$$LATITUDE_HERE!=null`? shouldnt i use && instead of $$ in android (java)... when i did with $$, gives out an error..

Comment: Instead of LONGITUDE_HERE= String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
 you can use 
LONGITUDE_HERE=""+location.getLongitude();

Comment: String.valueOf feels much more easier for me... Thz anyway

Comment: for other people:both  string.valueof and ""+ location.~ works fine. No problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do:

1) Declare your both `TextView'`s global

2) Declare your `latitude` and `longitude` variable global and then use

```
 longitude = location.getLongitude();
 latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

After than you can use both variables in sharing extra text or get text from your textview's

Comment: You should do some int <--> double conversion

Answer (score 0):

Make that variable `static` for location changed and use it in share intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create global variables for latitude and longitude.

And modify

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_placeholder);
TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_placeholder);
lattitudeString = location.getLatitude();
longitudeString = location.getLongitude();
longitude.setText("Longitude :" + location.getLongitude());
latitude.setText("Latitude : " + location.getLatitude());
}
```

and you can replace `LONGITUDE_HERE` and `LATITUDE_HERE` with the two variables.

Comment: `lattitude = location.getLongitude();` this should be `longitude = location.getLongitude();` right?